# How to manipulate the DOM in a VUE attribute / variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a very simple component that renders a HTML string:

```
<template>
  <v-list-item-content v-html="html_string">
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "HtmlRenderer",
    props: ['html_string']
</script>
```

The HTML string comes from an API in a parent component, and can contain basic HTML, like `<p>` and `<blockquote>` elements.

I'd like to manipulate the DOM of this HTML string with the following logic:

1. Find every `<blockquote>` and add a button before each element (there can be 0+)
2. Have this button toggle the `.active` class of the `<blockquote>`

How would I do the above two steps in the lifecycle of a VUE component? Can I call a function defined in the methods section of the component from the `<button>` that I injected?

Thanks

Comment: use a watcher listen to `html_string`, and process the html string there?

Answer (score 1):

Several hints:

- Update the html string directly before parsing. (Pretty bad idea IMO, I don't even know how you would attach events)
- Manipulate the DOM from the vanilla JS api after the component is mounted.
- Use the [render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#render) function of Vue component to render it the way you want

This last idea may be the most powerful, but it's not an easy path.

So I would:

1. Parse the html string myself, to separate each html tag.
2. Loop on it an render the tag with the render function
3. When you hit a `blockquote`, add the element the button you need

```js
interface HTMLTag {
   name: string,
   attributes: any[],
   childrens: HTMLTag[],
}

render (h: CreateElement) {
    // parseToHTMLTag doesn't exists, you'd have to make it yourself
    const parsedElements: HTMLTag[] = parseToHTMLTag(this['html_string'])
    
    // render manually every html tag you have with the render function
    parsedElements.forEach((tag) => {
       if (tag.name === 'blockquote') {
           renderButton()
       }
    
       renderTag(tag)
    })

    renderTag = (htmlTag: HTMLTag) => {
       return h(tag.name, {
          attrs: tag.attributes,
          childrens: render(tag.childrens)
       })
    }

    renderButton = () => {
       return h('button', { ... })
    }

}
```

This is just an idea but I think it's doable.
It's a lot of work though, I would not enjoy doing this! So good luck!